# Need Advice JSON on Android Online Database

Tags: android, json, database

i am now working on an android online database project. I create an app that can connect to the online database and bring the information to the user. 
Since i am not too familiar with java and JSON code, i browse on the internet and stackoverflow also and i find this code below. 
But i don't too understand with the code, what i ask is :
a. Where i should put the JSON Code?
b. Is this the code for taking the data from category table on online database?
c. Where i can put the URL for my online database?

Please help me sir.

NB. This is the code :

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements InternetConnectionListener, ApiHandler.ApiHandlerListener {

private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
private final int CATEGORY_ACTION = 1;
private CategorySelectionCallbacks mCallbacks;
private ArrayList<Category> categoryList;
private ListView categoryListView;
private InternetConnectionListener internetConnectionListener;

public HomeFragment() {

}

public static HomeFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
    HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    ((HomeActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    try {
        mCallbacks = (CategorySelectionCallbacks) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement CategorySelectionCallbacks.");
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    categoryListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.categoryListView);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (UtilMethods.isConnectedToInternet(getActivity())) {
        initCategoryList();
    } else {
        internetConnectionListener = (InternetConnectionListener) HomeFragment.this;
        showNoInternetDialog(getActivity(), internetConnectionListener,
                getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet),
                getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet_text),
                getResources().getString(R.string.retry_string),
                getResources().getString(R.string.exit_string), CATEGORY_ACTION);
    }

}

//! function for populate category list
private void initCategoryList() {

    /**
     * json is populating from text file. To make api call use ApiHandler class
     *
     *  <CODE>ApiHandler apiHandler = new ApiHandler(this, URL_GET_CATEGORY);</CODE> <BR>
     *  <CODE>apiHandler.doApiRequest(ApiHandler.REQUEST_GET);</CODE> <BR>
     *
     * You will get the response in onSuccessResponse(String tag, String jsonString) method
     * if successful api call has done. Do the parsing as the following.
     */

    String jsonString = loadJSONFromAsset(getActivity(), "get_category_id_list");
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
        categoryList = new ArrayList<Category>();

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            Category category = new Category();// buat variabel category

            category.setId(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(JF_ID));
            category.setTitle(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(JF_TITLE));
            category.setIconUrl(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(JF_ICON));

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(JF_BACKGROUND_IMAGE))) {
                category.setImageUrl(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(JF_BACKGROUND_IMAGE));
            }
            categoryList.add(category);
        }

        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                categoryListView.setAdapter(new CategoryAdapter(getActivity(), mCallbacks, categoryList));
            }
        });

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionEstablished(int code) {
    if (code == CATEGORY_ACTION) {
        initCategoryList();
    }
}

@Override
public void onUserCanceled(int code) {
    if (code == CATEGORY_ACTION) {
        getActivity().finish();
    }
}

//! catch json response from here
@Override
public void onSuccessResponse(String tag, String jsonString) {
    //! do same parsing as done in initCategoryList()
}

//! detect response error here
@Override
public void onFailureResponse(String tag) {

}

//! callback interface listen by HomeActivity to detect user click on category
public static interface CategorySelectionCallbacks {
    void onCategorySelected(String catID, String title);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I believe this code is coming from an app called finder,

You need to change this

```
 String jsonString = loadJSONFromAsset(getActivity(), "get_category_id_list");
```

to

```
ApiHandler apiHandler = new ApiHandler(this, "get_category_id_list");
        apiHandler.doApiRequest(ApiHandler.REQUEST_GET);
```

This will cause the `ApiHandler.java` file to handle your request to the server instead of calling a local JSON file in the assets folder. When you are done. Go to you `Constants.java` file and change  the value of `URL_APB_AP` to you API url. Do same to all lines that call the `loadJSONFromAsset` function.

Hope this helps you.